# What sourcebook has 0th-level psionic powers?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, psionics

So, I've heard about the existence of 0-level psionic powers somewhere in D&D, which would be a fantastic boon for low-level psionic characters (and a nice feature for mid- and high-level ones).

The problem is, I can't find the source of them. Is it an optional rule from printed books? Dragon Magazine? Mind's Eye? Pathfinder rulebooks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Secrets of Sarlona

SoS presents a number of arcane cantrips as 1st level powers, see page 133.

There are no rules for actual 0th-level powers in D&D 3.5. They were present under the name of "Talents" in the 3.0 Psionics Handbook and reintroduced in Pathfinder, but they skipped 3.5.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder which would be easier to adapt to 3.5, the rules from 3.0 or from Pathfinder?

Comment: I don't know which would be easier, but the Pathfinder ones would be more worth having once the adaptation was complete. They are much better designed, and learned a lot from the mistakes made by 3.0/3.5. Just make sure to account for the general power inflation from 3.5 to Pathfinder. Last thing we need is another round of people insisting Psionics is broken because they had bad experiences playing mangled versions with stuff the actual books disallowed for good reason.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of a 3.5 sourcebook that presents 0th-level psionic powers, though there may be one out there.

For Pathfinder, the Psionics rules are all to be found in publications by Dreamscarred press. The core book, Psionics Unleashed, provided the Psion class with a limited number of "talents" that acted like level 0 powers. The Psionics Expanded series expanded these talents into actual level-0 psionic powers, and since the recently released [Ultimate Psionics](http://paizo.com/products/btpy91t5/discuss?Ultimate-Psionics) combined and updated the rules from these two sources, it probably also provides rules for level-0 powers (probably in a less haphazard manner than PsiExpanded, since that was a series of small supplements).

Here is the [SRD for Psionic Talents](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/psionic-talents).

Comment: I'd say this is pretty accurate considering the first line of the linked SRD page states "Talents are 0th-level psionic powers..."

Answer (score 5):

The "talents" from Pathfinder can be adapted for 3.5, but there are no 0-level powers in an official 3.5 book from Wizards.

Answer (score 1):

This is the source you are looking for: http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20010928a

Comment: Good find! As a heads-up, link-only answers are generally not received as well on this stack. If you edit your answer to add a brief description and address the question, you're likely to get more upvotes. (That's especially true since you're pointing to a 3.0 source to answer a 3.5 question.)

Comment: It would be useful to highlight whether this is 3e or 3.5e.

Comment: Looking at the power descriptions, I'd say it's for 3.0, since the disciplines are followed by attributes in parentheses (Like Psychometabolism (str))...  Something I have not seen in 3.5 materials